# Ordered Map in C++

Tags: c++, hash-map

This is the final version of my ordered-by-insertion map in C++. What do you think and how can I make it even better? I'm open to all kind of suggestions! I intend to make a similar class, this time, a ordered-by-insertion set!

```
#ifndef CORE_TABLE_H
#define CORE_TABLE_H

template <typename K, typename V>
class core_table {
    using value = std::pair<K, V>;
    using storage = std::list<value>;
    using iterator = typename storage::iterator;

    struct compare {
        using is_transparent = void;

        bool operator ()(iterator const x, iterator const y) const {
            return x->first < y->first;
        }

        bool operator ()(K const & k, iterator const y) const {
            return k < y->first;
        }

        bool operator ()(iterator const x, K const & k) const {
            return x->first < k;
        }
    };

    storage list;
    std::set<iterator, compare> data;

public:
    core_table() = default;

    core_table(core_table const & ct) {
        for (auto const & e : ct.list) {
            push(e.first, e.second);
        }
    }

    core_table(std::initializer_list<value> const il) {
        for (auto const & e : il) {
            push(e.first, e.second);
        }
    }

    core_table & unshift(K const & k, V const & v) {
        auto const it = data.find(k);
        if (it != data.end()) {
            (*it)->second = v;
            return *this;
        }
        data.emplace(list.emplace(list.begin(), k, v));
        return *this;
    }

    core_table & push(K const & k, V const & v) {
        auto const it = data.find(k);
        if (it != data.end()) {
            (*it)->second = v;
            return *this;
        }
        data.emplace(list.emplace(list.end(), k, v));
        return *this;
    }

    bool shift() {
        return remove(list.front().first);
    }

    bool pop() {
        return remove(list.back().first);
    }

    bool remove(K const & k) {
        auto const it = data.find(k);
        if (it != data.end()) {
            list.erase(*it);
            data.erase(it);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    core_table & clear() {
        list.clear();
        data.clear();
        return *this;
    }

    core_table & swap(core_table & ct) {
        list.swap(ct.list);
        data.swap(ct.data);
        return *this;
    }

    bool is_empty() const {
        return list.empty();
    }

    bool contains(K const & k) const {
        return data.find(k) != data.end();
    }

    size_t length() const {
        return list.size();
    }

    iterator begin() {
        return list.begin();
    }

    iterator end() {
        return list.end();
    }

    core_table head() const {
        if (is_empty()) {
            return {};
        }
        return {{list.front().first, list.front().second}};
    }

    core_table last() const {
        if (is_empty()) {
            return {};
        }
        return {{list.back().first, list.back().second}};
    }

    core_table lead() const {
        if (is_empty()) {
            return {};
        }
        core_table output {*this};
        output.pop();
        return output;
    }

    core_table tail() const {
        if (is_empty()) {
            return {};
        }
        core_table output {*this};
        output.shift();
        return output;
    }

    core_table edge() const {
        if (length() < 3) {
            return {*this};
        }
        return {
            {list.front().first, list.front().second},
            {list.back().first, list.back().second}
        };
    }

    core_table bulk() const {
        if (length() < 3) {
            return {};
        }
        core_table output {*this};
        output.shift();
        output.pop();
        return output;
    }

    std::vector<K> keys() const {
        std::vector<K> output;
        output.reserve(length());
        for (auto const & e : list) {
            output.emplace_back(e.first);
        }
        return output;
    }

    std::vector<V> values() const {
        std::vector<V> output;
        output.reserve(length());
        for (auto const & e : list) {
            output.emplace_back(e.second);
        }
        return output;
    }

    V & operator [](K const & k) {
        return (*data.find(k))->second;
    }

    V const & operator [](K const & k) const {
        return (*data.find(k))->second;
    }

    core_table & operator =(std::initializer_list<value> const il) {
        return swap(core_table {il});
    }

    explicit operator bool() const {
        return true;
    }

    bool operator ==(core_table const & ct) const {
        return list == ct.list;
    }

    bool operator !=(core_table const & ct) const {
        return !(*this == ct);
    }

    bool operator <(core_table const & ct) const {
        return list < ct.list;
    }

    bool operator >(core_table const & ct) const {
        return ct < *this;
    }

    bool operator <=(core_table const & ct) const {
        return !(*this > ct);
    }

    bool operator >=(core_table const & ct) const {
        return !(*this < ct);
    }
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

- You have written a copy constructor, so I should also be seeing an assignment operator. The default one will copy iterators over—not what I think you want!

  Also, you haven't defined the move operators for your class.
- Although you have a swap method, you usually want to also have a free-standing version of the swap. This is useful when using templated functions, as most people will use the free-standing version of `swap()`. Just make it delegate to your existing member function:

  ```
  friend void swap(core_table& lhs, core_table& rhs) {
      lhs.swap(rhs);
  }
  ```

  Note that the swap operator is usually marked as `noexcept` to indicate that it can't throw an exception.
- You define a non-const version of `begin()` and `end()`, but usually there are a couple of other versions to handle getting const iterators.

  ```
  const_iterator begin()  const;
  const_iterator cbegin() const;
  const_iterator end()    const;
  const_iterator cend()   const;
  ```